# Why doesnt the sum of $\tan(1/n)$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \tan(\frac{1}{n})$$

Let $u = 1/n$

$u(1) = 1$

$\lim_{x\to \infty} u = 1/x = 0$

$$= \sum_{u=1}^{0} \tan(u)$$

Which by definition converges to $0$?

Comment: The **sequence** whose $n$-th term is $\tan(1/n)$  converges to $0$. The **series** $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \tan(1/n)$ does not converge.

Comment: No, the substitution you're performing is complete nonsense.

Comment: In the sum you wrote, you would necessarily need for $u$ to take on the values $1,\frac12, \frac13,\frac14,\cdots$, not just the two values $1$ and $0$. Changing the indexing system in no way changes the actual terms appearing in the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution you're performing has no sense. If it had, then *every* series would converge to zero:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)=\sum_{u=1}^{0}f(1/u)=0
$$
which is clearly absurd. The notation
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)
$$
means
$$
\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m}f(n)
$$
so of sums with more terms as $m$ gets bigger.

There are similarities between series and integrals, but not so easy as you think they are.

Comment: So you do not change the upperbound, but you **can** change the lower index bound?

Comment: @Amad27 A finite number of initial terms can always be omitted: they change the sum, but not the character of the series (convergent or not).

Answer (score 8):

For $x \in (0,\pi/2)$, $x < \tan x$.

Hence for all $N \geq 1$,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \tan(1/n) > \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$$

As the RHS series diverges, so does the original series.

Comment: $\LaTeX$ hint: use `\left` and `\right` before parentheses, then `\left(\frac1n\right)` will give $\left(\frac1n\right)$.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't look as good, so I've left it as is ;-)

Comment: Oops, sorry, MSE didn't display your comment indicating the preference to keep the original formatting, but I've reverted my edit back to your original.

Comment: To be pedantic, your inequality is nonsense, as it claims $\infty>\infty$. If you replace it by $\ge$, all is well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've changed the upper limits of summation to $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $tan(x) > x$ for all $0 < x < \pi/2$, and $\sum_n \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$\tan\frac{1}{n}\geq 0$ for all n, and
$$\tan{\frac{1}{n}}\geq\frac{1}{n}$$ and  for all $n$, therefore, it doesn't converge.